# how to reach machine port from docker container

Tags: docker

I have `docker` container with running `node` app. Other `node` app running on machine level at 7000 port. My goal is to create a request from `docker` to `machine` app using `axios`.

docker was started with:

`docker run -p 3000:3000 -p 4000:4000 -i -t gepick_env:latest -d --network='host'`

client on the docker snippet:

```
 ....
 axios.post(                                                                                                           
    'http://localhost:7000/predict',                                                                                    
    matchesToPredict                                                                                                    
  ).then(res => {...})
...
```

I tried `test` using curl from local.

```
➜  gepick-devenv git:(master) ✗ curl http://localhost:7000/
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Tried did the same from `docker`:

First I logged to `docker` by the command:

`docker exec -i -t 6c9036c76463 /bin/bash`

and tried:

```
[root@6c9036c76463 /]# curl http://localhost:7000/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to ::1: Network is unreachable
```

`

Comment: Docker-specific options need to come _before_ the image name.  `--network=host` is getting passed to your application as an argument; Docker isn’t handling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, docker creates and uses network `172.17.0.0/16` for containers.

In this network the address `172.17.0.1` is assigned to the host where docker daemon is running (i.e: your machine).

So pointing to that address should work:

```
 curl http://172.18.0.1:7000/
```

You can get what is the gateway address of a specific container by executing:

```
docker inspect --format "{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{ .Gateway }}{{end}}" \
   <container-name>
```